# Рисование фигур в php

Tags: php

Пробую рисовать в PHP но появилась идея залить на фон изображение, любое 
Возможно ли установить на фон любое изображение?
Если да ..то как ?
Моя попытка --

```html
<?php
  $i = imageCreate(200, 300);
  $color = imageColorAllocate($i, 255, 255, 0);
  imageSetPixel($i, 30, 50, $color);



  $color = imageColorAllocate($i, 0, 255, 0);
  imagePolygon($i, array(50, 0, 90, 20, 100, 60, 75, 100, 25, 100, 0, 60, 10, 20), 7, $color);

  Header("Content-type: image/png");
  imageJpeg($i);
  imageDestroy($i);
?>
```

Результат :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте прочитать _всю_ справку по GD, а потом начинать с ней работать. там не так уж много функций. достаточно их краткие описания прочитать. чтобы понять, что и как делать.

Comment: @teran вот для этого я задал вопрос ...